# Add a new line in file using MPI

Tags: c++, file, io, mpi

I am using MPI to store some data to a file:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
int num_procs = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();
int rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();

MPI_Offset offset;
MPI_File file;
MPI_Status status;
const int msgsize = 6;
char message[msgsize + 1];

if ((rank % 2) == 0) strcpy(message, "Hello ");
else strcpy(message, "World!");

MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "helloworld2.txt", MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY,
        MPI_INFO_NULL, &file);
offset = (msgsize * rank);
MPI_File_seek(file, offset, MPI_SEEK_SET);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    MPI_File_write(file, message, msgsize, MPI_CHAR, &status);
}
MPI_File_close(&file);

MPI::Finalize();
//    return 0;
}
```

I would like the message to be written in a new line after each time step (an equivalent to std::endl in serial mode). Is there a way to do this using MPI?

Comment: Can you not simply append a `\n` character to the end of the message?

Comment: Does not work! I think I have to redefine the offset at each time step but I don't know which value to put when I a move from a line to another.

Comment: Solved! I must use MPI_SEEK_END instead of MPI_SEEK_SET as a parameter in MPI_File_seek.

Comment: @user3492799, you should post your comment as an answer and mark it as correct. That way future visitors will know what the solution is.